# How can I automate in Wordpress a video player that has a thumbnail & HTML description?

Tags: xml, video, wordpress, playlists

Basically I am in need of a video solution that allows for thumbnails (in some sort of jQuery carousel), a video playback area and a custom HTML area. Almost like using playlists I guess. Would XML be a good way to go?

I was wondering if there is a Wordpress plugin/solution that can handle it?

Going into more detail I am in need of a list of thumbnails that a user can click on. When they click on a thumbnail the video comes up larger above it and to the left of that larger video will be a custom HTML description applicable to just that video. Meaning when a thumbnail is clicked the video and description must change together.

Any links, tutorials, advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes ! XML is better way to fulfill your requirement. Obviously your XML is light weight + server sided file so its quite secure and if you provide proper tag formatting then you can use xml file as per your requirement ! Kindly I prefer XML because I have used in many cases.

I am giving you one format, from that you can get idea what you should do ?

```
<rootnode>
  <songs>
    <id> 0000-000-000 </id> // Autogenerted - unique identifier
    <name> _Name_ </name>
    <path> _path_ </path>

    <id> 0000-000-001 </id> // Autogenerted - unique identifier
    <name> _Name_ </name>
    <path> _path_ </path>
  </songs>
</rootnode>
```

Enjoy Playing with XML !